# Convert cURL to ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, curl

I'm looking for a way to convert the following cURL to ASP.Net.

```
curl -F f=@example.pdf "https://pdftables.com/api?key=ZZZ999&format=xml"
```

I've used the following function extensively to get virtually any URL/content, but I'm lost on how to include a file located on the hosted web server.

```
Public Shared Function GetRemoteURL(getURL As String) As String
    Dim objReq As HttpWebRequest
    Dim objRsp As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
    Dim objRdr As StreamReader
    Dim objRes As String = ""
    Try
        objReq = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(getURL), HttpWebRequest)
        objRsp = DirectCast(objReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        objRdr = New StreamReader(objRsp.GetResponseStream())
        objRes = objRdr.ReadToEnd()
    Catch
        objRes = ""
    Finally
        If Not objRsp Is Nothing Then objRsp.Close()
    End Try
    Return objRes.ToString()
End Function
```

Any advice/direction would be deeply appreciated.

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to set the request body, something like:

```
Public Function GetRemoteURL(getURL As String) As String
    Dim objReq As HttpWebRequest
    Dim objRsp As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
    Dim objRdr As StreamReader
    Dim objRes As String = "" 
    Try
        objReq = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(getURL), HttpWebRequest)

        objReq.Method = "POST"
        Dim postData = "f=@example.pdf"
        Dim encoding As New ASCIIEncoding()
        Dim bytes = encoding.GetBytes(postData) 
        objReq.ContentLength = bytes.Length
        Dim stream = objReq.GetRequestStream()
        stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)

        objRsp = DirectCast(objReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        objRdr = New StreamReader(objRsp.GetResponseStream())
        objRes = objRdr.ReadToEnd()
    Catch
        objRes = ""
    Finally
        If Not objRsp Is Nothing Then objRsp.Close()
    End Try
    Return objRes.ToString()
End Function
```

note: i didn't test this so it might not directly work.

Comment: Let me give it a spint.   Thanks for quick reply

Comment: I just edited and added objReq.Method="POST", this is probably required.

Comment: i think i misunderstood the question a bit.  you'll need to read in your pdf file and convert it to bytes, then write that to the stream. more information can be found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data

Comment: I found a c# example.   working with it now.  However, I can use your answer for another solution.